# Why the parameter syntax operator "[" is used in this case ? As Like" "['i']" " I am using as a script for RGSS, RPG Maker XP with win32api and ruby

Tags: ruby, winapi

In this case:

```
x = Win32API.new("user32","GetAsyncKeyState",['i'],'i').call(0x01)
```

I understood the code as a whole, it returns a value when the left mouse button is clicked. However, I would like to know why the programmer used this symbol `[` like that `['i']` as a parameter. I know that the parameter is for the type of import and that the `i` means integer, but why the use of the `[' ']`?

Comment: _"why the use of the `[' ']`"_ – it's an `'i'` within `[ ]`, not an `i` within `[' ']`. From a Ruby perspective, a single `i` would denote a local variable (or a method) called `i`. To pass it as a value (i.e. the letter "i" itself), you have to use the _string_ `'i'`. The brackets are simply an [array literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Array+Literals) – there's no such thing as a "parameter syntax operator".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of `Win32API.new()` is an **array** of types, as a function can have more than 1 input parameter.

[`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) has 1 input parameter which is an integer, so the `['i']` is an array of 1 type to reflect that fact.

The subsequent `'i'` is not an array, because a function can have only 1 return value. In this case, [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) returns an integer as output.

This is mentioned in the book ["Ruby in a Nutshell"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ruby-in-a/0596002149/re111.html) by Yukihiro Matsumoto:

> `Win32API::new(dll, proc, import, export)`
>
> Returns the object representing the `Win32API` function specified by `proc` name in `dll`, which has the signature specified by `import` and `export`. **`import` is an array of strings denoting types. `export` is a type specifying string.**

Perhaps the below example would make it more clear to you:

[Calling Windows APIs](https://rubyfu.net/module-0x5-or-exploitation-kung-fu/calling-windows-apis)

> ```cpp
> int WINAPI MessageBox(
>    _In_opt_ HWND    hwnd,
>    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpText,
>    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpCaption,
>    _In_     UINT    uType
> );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```rb
> require "Win32API"
>
> title = "Rubyfu!"
> message = "You've called the Windows API Successfully! \n\n@Rubyfu"
>
> api = Win32API.new('user32', 'MessageBoxA', ['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'], 'I')
> api.call(0, message, title, 0)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Note that Win32API was deprecated with Ruby 1.9.1. The current version is merely a wrapper around [`Fiddle`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html) and you are advised to use `Fiddle` directly as a more recent alternative.

The [`Fiddle::Import`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle/Importer.html) module provides a simple DSL to declare the C functions and additional types like `SHORT` inside a Ruby module, e.g.:

```
require 'fiddle/import'

module User32
  extend Fiddle::Importer
  dlload 'user32'
  typealias 'SHORT', 'short'
  extern 'SHORT GetAsyncKeyState(int)'
end
```

Afterwards, you can call the C function as a Ruby class method of that module:

```
x = User32.GetAsyncKeyState(1)
```